# Can not figure out why "if (isset($_POST['Enter Data']))" is constantly false

Tags: php, html

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Create or Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "Welcome Screen.php" method = "post">
   <div align = "center">
             <input type = "submit" name = "Enter Data" value = "Enter Data"/><br />
             <input type = "submit" name = "Search Data" value = "Search For Data"/><br />
   </div>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    echo "here";
    if (isset($_POST['Enter Data']))
    {
        echo "Here1";
        header("Location: Enter Data.php");
        exit();
    }
    else if (isset($_POST["Search Data"]))
    {
        header("Location: Search Data.php");
        echo "here2";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can not seem to figure out why it is not at least entering inside the if statements. I am horribly new to PHP/HTML and will welcome any help. I have looked up this problem and can not seem to find a post that seems to help me solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: Try a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's actually being submitted. At a guess, you should remove the spaces and have `name='Enter Data'` instead of `name = ...`

Comment: You've left out a lot of information in your question, such as the version of PHP you are using, the name and version of the webserver you are using, whether you are using FPM, the configuration file of the webserver you are using, the OS you have the server running, the specific method you are using to generate the POST data, and so forth.

Comment: Where is the session_start?

Comment: what the heck `session_start` does have to do with the question?

Comment: Wow thank you guys for the quick responses. I am currently running Version: 5.5.31, and unfortunately I am kinda clueless on most of those questions besides the fact I am running it on a localhost on MacOS.

Comment: Sorry for a second post, when I run "var_dump($_POST) I am getting "array(1) { ["Enter_Data"]=> string(10) "Enter Data" }" for the instance when I click the "Enter Data" button

Comment: @Federico it looked like a session variable, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @xXNathan360Xx, and what's the output when you click the `Search Data` button? @andreas, where you saw a session variable?

Comment: @Federico "array(1) { ["Search_Data"]=> string(15) "Search For Data" }" seems to be the output for that one. Also am I supposed to have a session variable? If so I will need to do some research into what it does/how to use it.

Comment: _seems to be the output for that one_ - so that's what you'd expect from your code. what's your problem exactly?

Comment: @Federico When I click on either button, it does not seem to be getting inside the if statement and echoing "here1" or "here2". Sorry if it was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (isset($_POST['Enter Data']))
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['Enter_Data']))
```

and

```
else if (isset($_POST["Search Data"]))
```

to

```
else if (isset($_POST["Search_Data"]))
```

The reason for that is that PHP will always replace the spaces with underlines in your $_GET / $_POST field. You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

> Typically, PHP does not alter the names of variables when they are passed into a script. However, it should be noted that the dot (period, full stop, [and space]) is not a valid character in a PHP variable name. [...] it is important to note that PHP will automatically replace any dots in incoming variable names with underscores.

Comment: So to make sure I understand this correctly. In "header("Location: Enter_Data.php");" to represent the white space should I use an underscore or should I just encapsulate Enter Data.php with quotations to signify the space between the words

Comment: the problem is just with the key of the `$_POST` array, just that. If you don't want have this problem, just remove the space from your input names, `name="enter_data"` => `$_POST['enter_data']`

Comment: Alright thank you, now to just get the pages to interact together :)